# Como enfocar la tecla ENTER en un botón

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, css3

estoy haciendo un formulario de logueo con Angular, el cual tiene un campo para el usuario, otro para la contraseña, y al lado de este campo tiene un ícono que si lo presionas, te permite ver la contraseña que escribiste, y debajo se encuentra el botón para ingresar. Cual es el problema? al terminar de escribir la contraseña, si presionas ENTER, hace click sobre el ícono, mostrando la contraseña. Como puedo hacer para enfocar la tecla ENTER en otro botón para que me anule eso?
El código es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="password">
    <mat-form-field class="form-field">
      <input  class="inputpass" matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña" [formControl]="passFormControl" formControlName="pass">
      <button class="button" mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
      <mat-icon class="icono">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
      </button>
  </mat-form-field>
  </div>
    <input id ="boton-login" class="BotonLogin" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
```

Comment: El enter lo envía dado que es un formulario, puedes buscar el código de la tecla enter y tratar el evento, de tal manera anular-lo con event.preventDefault()

Comment: No estoy seguro de los detalles de Angular pues hace mucho no lo uso, pero veo probable que el form este usando el primer <button> que encuentra como boton de submit. Intenta agregar type="button" al boton que controla la visibilidad del password y type="submit" al que envia el formulario.

Comment: Graciass muchachos, me sirvió su ayuda, resolví